# Empty JSON with Nodejs writeFile

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, writefile

I am trying to write to a JSON file with NodeJS. After writing I have an empty JSON file when using node's `writeFile` function. When I `console.log` all the data is correct in my terminal.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

fs.readFile('items.csv', 'utf-8', (err,data) => {

  let lines = data.split('\n')

  let result = []

  let headers = lines[0].split(',')

  const noClass = 'NoClass'
  result[noClass] = 0

  for(var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {

    let currentLine = lines[i].split(',')

    if(currentLine[2] === '' || currentLine[2] === undefined) {
      result[noClass]++
    } else {
      let merchandiseHierarchy = currentLine[2].split(' : ')

      let subClass = merchandiseHierarchy[2]

      if(!result[subClass]) {
        result[subClass] = 0
      }
      result[subClass]++
    }

  }

  console.log(result)
  fs.writeFile('items.json', result)

})
```

Comment: You forgot to stringify `result`

Comment: When I stringify it the array becomes empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the combination of:

```
let result = []
```

and

```
const noClass = 'NoClass'
result[noClass] = 0
```

An array `[]` does not have properties that will be serialized when saved as JSON.
If you want to use an object with properties, then it has to be:

```
let result = {}
```

Beside that you need to write:

```
fs.writeFile('items.json', JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: Actually that's what the problem is. I was supposed use an object

Answer (score 1):

You should change the writing  to file code to, `fs.writeFileSync('items.json',JSON.stringify(result))`

This will eliminate the two issues you have:

1. You need to convert your `result` object to a string representation. If you want the file to be human readable, I would recommend, `JSON.stringify(result, null,2)`, this will indent the file nicely. Do remember that if the result object is big and the output is again going to be programatically consumed, I would recommend leaving out the indentation as it has a space overhead.
2. `writeFileSync` will ensure your program flow doesn't continue till the file write operation is done.

Comment: I still get an empty array

Comment: post output of the actual file, if by empty array you mean [], that would mean that your object is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This fs.writeFile('items.json', result) will never work. fs.writeFile takes 3 - 4 argument so to say and your result must be turn to a string using JSON.stringify() then pass your result into the bracket

Try

fs.writeFile('items.json', JSON.stringify(result), "utf8", (err) => console.log(err));

That should do it and asychronously

Comment: `fs.writeFile` takes 2 parameters, data and options, you can add more options. For example "utf8" is the default, so adding it is redundant. Btw, that is also not what the question is about.